# Node JS / mongoose backend returning error response in html

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I created a node JS backend with mongoose using a /signup endpoint to signup users. Now I'm calling the BE using an angular front end. When there are no errors, it all seems to work just fine. However when I try to create a duplicate email address (thus generating an error) I get a response that is in HTML ? which I am not sure how to process. my code

FE (angular 5):

```
public signUp(data: RegistrationParams): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post(this._actionUrl, JSON.stringify(data), this._requestOptions)
      .map((response: any) => {
        return JSON.parse(response._body);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('error:', e);

      });
  }
```

this logs the following on an error:

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Error: something went wrong while adding data to the database E11000 duplicate key error collection: testdb.users index: user.email_1 dup key: { : null }<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at SignUpController.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/usr/src/app/src/api/v1/SignupController.ts:29:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at throw (native)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at rejected (/usr/src/app/src/api/v1/SignupController.ts:17:65)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

BE (nodeJS):

```
@JsonController()
@Service()
export class SignUpController {
  @Post('/signup')
  public async addUser(@Body() body: any, @Res() resp: Response): Promise<T> {
    const newUser = new USER(body);
    try {
      await newUser.save();
      return <DatabaseResponse>{
        successful: true,
        message: 'succes',
      };
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error('something went wrong while adding data to the database ' + err.message);
    }
  }
}
```

This is just one of the ways I have tried to throw an error, but everything keeps responding with html. Is that correct? not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Edit:

Error from the server:

```
{ WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error collection: testdb.users index: user.email_1 dup key: { : null }","op":{"_id":"5af049f9312e7c07252eaf64","email":"mischa.boldyISC@nl.ibm.com","firstName":"weqwewq","lastName":"qwqew","phoneNumber":"12345663343","plateNumber":"123456","role":"User","__v":0}})
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:528:15
    at handleCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)
    at resultHandler (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:454:5)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:541:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  name: 'BulkWriteError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: testdb.users index: user.email_1 dup key: { : null }',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  index: 0,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: testdb.users index: user.email_1 dup key: { : null }',
  getOperation: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function],
  result: 
   BulkWriteResult {
     ok: [Getter],
     nInserted: [Getter],
     nUpserted: [Getter],
     nMatched: [Getter],
     nModified: [Getter],
     nRemoved: [Getter],
     getInsertedIds: [Function],
     getUpsertedIds: [Function],
     getUpsertedIdAt: [Function],
     getRawResponse: [Function],
     hasWriteErrors: [Function],
     getWriteErrorCount: [Function],
     getWriteErrorAt: [Function],
     getWriteErrors: [Function],
     getLastOp: [Function],
     getWriteConcernError: [Function],
     toJSON: [Function],
     toString: [Function],
     isOk: [Function] } }
add obj 2 E11000 duplicate key error collection: testdb.users index: user.email_1 dup key: { : null }
Error: something went wrong while adding data to the database E11000 duplicate key error collection: testdb.users index: user.email_1 dup key: { : null }
    at SignUpController.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/src/api/v1/SignupController.ts:29:13)
    at throw (native)
    at rejected (/usr/src/app/src/api/v1/SignupController.ts:17:65)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Comment: You must have an entry point for your app. Can you start your app from your server and tell me the error you get in your terminal? If you use nodemon just type nodemon otherwise node app.js or whatever

Comment: I can add the error from the terminal, but not sure if that is the problem since I'm just using the error message from the error to push the error up

Answer (score 0):

your users model might have email field make sure the unique field is false it does not allows duplicate entries.

```
email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
        trim:true
    }
```